# seeing source code of objects in a python module

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I came up with this question when I was trying to use pygame. I wrote the following line

```
pygame.time.
```

but pyCharm didn't give me a list of methods to choose. I wanted to use `pygame.time.Clock()` but when this happened I tried to see the source code of time but I couldn't. I was just able to see the source code of pygame module and in that, there was just the following line on 'time':

```
try:
    import pygame.time
except (ImportError, IOError):
    time = MissingModule("time", geterror(), 1)
```

So my question is that, what is 'time' object and where is it? is it just a compiled python file that came with pygame when I installed it? Can I see the methods inside it or is there a way to let pyCharm suggest the methods inside of it?

Comment: PyGame is wrapper on library [SDL 1.2](https://www.libsdl.org) created in C/C++  and compiled to machine code (files `.dll` on Windows, and `.so` on Linux). But you can still see all in [official documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/) - ie. [pygame.time](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html)

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is that, what is 'time' object and where is it?

`time` is not an object it is a [module](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).
[Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) is well documented. A complete documentation of the `pygame.time` module can be found at [`pygame.time`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html).

It is not necessary to import the module. Via `pygame.time` you can access all objects of the module. However, you can import all objects form the module with:

```py
from pygame.time import *
```